# Error while building an android app using flutter and vscode

Tags: android, gradle, visual-studio-code, flutter

I am trying to build an android app with flutter and vscode but I am continuously getting an error.

> Launching lib\main.dart on Micromax Q427 in debug mode...
>
> Error running Gradle: Exit code 1 from:
>   E:\Flutter\mytestapp\android\gradlew.bat app:properties: Starting a
>   Gradle Daemon, 2 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for
>   details Download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar
>   Download
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar
>   Download
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project
>   'android'.
>
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'. Could not
>   download builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.0.1)
>
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.0.1/builder-3.0.1.jar'.
> >     Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 26945712; received: 8650688 Could not download intellij-core.jar
> >     (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1) Could
> >     not get resource
> >     'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar'.
> >     Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 8234273; received: 6553552
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with
>   --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 14m 39s Please review your Gradle project setup in the
>   android/ folder. Exited (sigterm)

I have tried many solutions but nothing worked also flutter doctor shows no issue and I am not able to understand why I am getting this error while building my app.

I have also asked this query in github but got no reply so far here is the link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19614